# AngularJS. Clear $timeout when invoking angular-ui modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout, angular-ui

I have several `$timeout` expressions in Modal controller

```
App.controller('ModalCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        (function () {
            var timer = $timeout(function () {
                console.log('timer')
            }, 1000);
        })()
    }
})
```

I need to clear all the timers when invoking the modal:

```
App.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $timeout) {
    $scope.showMap = function () {
        var modal = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'modalap.html',
            controller: 'modalCtrl',
        })

        modal.result.then(function () { //fires when modal is resolving
        }, function () { //fires when modal is invoking
        });
    } })
```

How can I do that?

PS Sorry for bad code formatting. I don't know why but I cant format it better. I duplicated code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VzQLU/1/):

Comment: how can you inject a controller like that?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

The `$timeout` service returns a `Promise` object which can be used to cancel the timeout.

```
// Start a timeout
var promise = $timeout(function() {}, 1000);

// Stop the pending timeout
$timeout.cancel(promise);
```

To cancel all pending timeouts, you need to maintain a list of promises and cancel the complete list when you open the modal.

Answer (score 2):

You may also let them cancel themselves by doing this...

```
(function(){
  var timer = $timeout(function(){
    console.log(timer.$$timeoutId);
    $timeout.cancel(timer);
  }, 1000);
})();
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. Why would you cancel a `$timeout` that is already called?

Comment: I wonder if Angular keeps listeners on that timeout. It looks like so because if you call lots of timeouts, memory keeps growing and eventually lead to a memory leek.

Comment: I guess you cooooould do that.

Comment: @pixelfreak Because we can and it's free !