# Clear Angular timeout inside function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, timeout

I've built a very simply slider with Angular like so:

```
$scope.slider = {};
$scope.slider.pane = 1;
$scope.slider.auto = true;

var slider = function(){
  $timeout(function(){
    if ($scope.slider.pane === 4) $scope.slider.pane = 1;
    else $scope.slider.pane ++;
    slider();
  }, 4000);
}
slider();
```

The slider function creates a timeout loop to change the value of `slider.pane` every 4s. In the HTML I have a link that when clicked sets the value `slider.auto` to `false`.

```
<a href="" ng-click="slider.auto=false">Stop slider</a>
```

When this is clicked, it needs to stop the timeout loop. It may be in the middle of a cycle at the time, so I need to clear the timeout, but it's inside a function so not sure how to access it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21019006/3894168 might help.

Comment: @Sourabh- thanks but this doesn't work. The promise variable would not be accessible outside my slider function.

Comment: You can make your promise as a global variable to access it outside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `$timeout.cancel` function:

```
var timeout;
$scope.cancelTimer = function() {
    $scope.slider.auto=false;
    $timeout.cancel(timeout);
};

var slider = function(){
  timeout = $timeout(function(){
    if ($scope.slider.pane === 4) $scope.slider.pane = 1;
    else $scope.slider.pane ++;
    slider();
  }, 4000);
}
slider();

//HTML
<a href="" ng-click="cancelTimer()">Stop slider</a>
```

Comment: Isn't the timeout variable scoped within the slider function and therefore not accessible within the cancelTimer function?

Comment: Ah no I see you've made it global first

Comment: yeah its visible in both functions

Comment: Yeh that works great thanks. Don't know why I didn't think to create it as a global variable like that

Comment: it is not global variable, since $scope is inside a function.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$scope.slider = {};
$scope.slider.pane = 1;
$scope.slider.auto = true;
var promise;
var slider = function(){
  promise = $timeout(function(){
    if ($scope.slider.pane === 4) $scope.slider.pane = 1;
    else $scope.slider.pane ++;
    slider();
  }, 4000);
}
$scope.autoSliderFalse = function() {
    $scope.slider.auto = false;
    if(promise)
       $timeout.cancel(promise);
});
slider();
```

HTML

```
<a href="" ng-click="autoSliderFalse()">Stop slider</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `cancel` method as some people suggested here.

I actually think in your case you should use [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) instead of `$timeout`.

```
var interval = $interval(function(){
  if ($scope.slider.pane === 4) {
    $scope.slider.pane = 1;
  }
  else {
    $scope.slider.pane ++;
  }    
}, 4000);

$scope.stopSlider = function(){
  $interval.cancel(interval);
};

//html
<a href="" ng-click="stopSlider()">Stop slider</a>
```